# Jar to Eclipse Plugin conversion

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar, executable-jar

I have no knowledge about eclipse plugins and I'm trying to know feasibility of a situation.

I have a executable jar and I need to convert it into a eclipse plugin with no additional coding (cannot make changes to the jar or functionality) to my jar. Is there a way to convert my jar as an eclipse plugin? I need to click a button or something in eclipse and run the jar which fulfills its functionality?

Comment: You can write an Eclipse plugin which contains the jar and some new code to define the menu item / toolbar item and call the code in the jar.

Comment: @greg-449 Any suggestions on how I could do that?